# Quirky behaviour of CSS property "opacity"

Tags: html, css

While working on a task, where I had to have a fixed positioned toolbar at the top of a scrollable panel, I stumbled on this quirky(?) behaviour of the CSS property "opacity".

This [simplistic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJKaW/2/) is self explainatory, but to summarize:
If you have two DIVs, one is fixed positioned and the other one scrolls behind(?) the fixed one, then the translucent content (opacity < 1) in the scrollable div shows up over fixed div.
The opacity of the fixed div is of no consequence here.

While the problem goes away if I assign the fixed div a z-index greater than the scrollable div (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJKaW/5)), I am still curious to know why the opacity property behaves in a counter intuitive manner in this case.

Can some one please explain?

By the way, the behaviour is consistent across Chrome 35, FF 30 and IE 10.

Copying the code from jsfiddle here - as it's the norm.

**CSS**

```
.fixedOpaqueDiv {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ABABAB;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    padding-top: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.scrollingDiv {
    padding-top: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.opaque {
    opacity: 1;
}

.translucent {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="fixedOpaqueDiv">I am a div with fixed position,
        <BR>with same z-index as the div below.
        <BR>I am supposed to be Opaque, but
        <BR>apparently I am opaque ONLY to the opaque divs below,
        <BR>and not to the translucent ones</div>
    <div class="scrollingDiv">
        <div class="translucent" style="color: red; padding: 5px;">^^^^^^^^ Scroll up ^^^^^^^^</div>
        <div class="opaque">Opaque 1</div>
        <div class="translucent">Translucent 1</div>
        <div class="opaque">Opaque 2</div>
        <div class="translucent">Translucent 2</div>
        <div class="opaque">Opaque 3</div>
        <div class="translucent">Translucent 3</div>
        <div class="opaque">Opaque 4</div>
        <div class="translucent">Translucent 4</div>
        <div class="opaque">Opaque 5</div>
        <div class="translucent">Translucent 5</div>
        <div class="opaque">Opaque 6</div>
        <div class="translucent">Translucent 6</div>
        <div class="opaque">Opaque 7</div>
        <div class="translucent">Translucent 7</div>
        <div class="opaque">Opaque 8</div>
        <div class="translucent">Translucent 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An interesting effect, certainly, but having two overlapping elements with the same z-index is asking for unpredictable behaviour in much the same way as in 3D graphics when you have two planes in the same place.

Comment: Agreed. Both the DIVs had same z-index as I had not explicitly assigned any to either of them. It all worked fine for a while as I did not have any translucent content in the scrolling panel, and the problem manifested only after someone skinned scrollable panel, and some translucent content made its way in. Ideally, the problem should have manifested from the start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that [an element with `opacity` less than 1 creates a stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency). Elements that don't establish stacking contexts will be obscured by your fixed-position element as expected, but the translucent elements that do establish stacking contexts will be painted in front because they appear after the fixed-position element in the source.

The reason setting `z-index` works is because you then make the stack level of the fixed-position element greater than that of the scrollable element's contents.

[Section 9.9 of the CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) summarizes the exact order in which elements are stacked. The last two items in the list are relevant to this scenario:

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. **the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.**
> 7. **the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).**

In #6, "child stacking contexts" refer to the translucent elements, and the positioned descendant is the fixed element. Once you set `z-index` on the fixed element, it falls under #7, which ensures it will appear over the translucent content.

Comment: Very, very interesting. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
So essentially, in my case, the stacking context (created on account of transparency) won over the fixed position div only because it appeared later in the HTML.
I verified this by reversing the order in which they appear in the html (and added a "top: 0px" to fixed positioned div), and got the desired effect without having to assign z-index to the positioned div - see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zJKaW/8/)